# Ndepend trial with teamcity

Tags: teamcity, ndepend

Can we configure Ndepend trial with teamcity to check ndepend report?

I tried using steps http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TeamCity.aspx. But I could not check the ndepend report in TeamCity.

Also, there is a dialog for asking ndepend version (open source/ trial/acedamic). I want to get rid of it. Is there any way out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using steps http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_TeamCity.aspx. But I could not check the ndepend report in TeamCity.

This should be possible.

> Also, there is a dialog for asking ndepend version (open source/ trial/acedamic). I want to get rid of it. Is there any way out

This is a non-removable limitation of the Trial version.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Continuous code quality measurement with NDepend and TeamCity](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/12/continuous-code-quality-measurement.html).